# Facebook Authentication using Koala does not work -- Fails to retrieve access_token

Tags: facebook, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is a web app that uses FB connect. Koala - Rails

Controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :parse_facebook_cookies

def parse_facebook_cookies
  @facebook_cookies ||= Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new('api_id','app_secret').get_user_info_from_cookie(cookies)
end

def index
  @users = User.all
end

def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @user = User.new
  @title = "sign up"
  require 'koala'

  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new
  @access_token = @facebook_cookies["access_token"]

  @user1 = @graph.get_object("me")
  @user.name = @user1["name"]
  @user.uid = @user1["id"]
  @user.save
end
end
```

It gives me the following error when executing: 
  @access_token = @facebook_cookies["access_token"]

"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

I appreciate any pointers to what may be going wrong! Thanks!